# How do I simulate a left truncated Weibull failure time data in R

Tags: r, simulation, survival-analysis, weibull

I want to simulate left truncated failure time data from Weibull distribution.
My objective is to simulate data and retrieve the coefficients(of x1,x2,x3,x4, and x5 which I used for the simulation) by fitting a Weibull regression model. Here the `xt=runif(N, 30, 80)` denotes the start of the study, `Tm <- qweibull(runif(N,pweibull(xt,shape = 7.5, scale = 82*exp(lp)),1), shape=7.5, scale=82*exp(lp))` variable denotes the failure time. But whenever I do the regression I am getting this warning message

````
Warning message:
In Surv(xt, time_M, event_M) : Stop time must be > start time, NA created```
````

This was my try:

```
N = 10^5
H <- within(data.frame(xt=runif(N, 30, 80), x1=rnorm(N, 2, 1), x2=rnorm(N, -2, 1)), {
  x3 <- rnorm(N, 0.5*x1 + 0.5*x2, 2)
  x4 <- rnorm(N, 0.3*x1 + 0.3*x2 + 0.3*x3, 2 )
  lp1 <- -2 + 0.5*x1 + 0.2*x2 + 0.1*x3 + 0.2*x4
  lp2 <- -2 + 0.5*x1 + 0.2*x2 + 0.1*x3 + 0.2*x4
  lp3 <- 0.5*x1 + 0.2*x2 + 0.1*x3 + 0.2*x4
  lp4 <- 0
  P1 <- exp(lp1)/(exp(lp2)+ exp(lp3)+1+exp(lp1))
  P2 <- exp(lp2)/(exp(lp1)+ exp(lp3)+1+exp(lp2))
  P3 <- exp(lp3)/(exp(lp2)+ exp(lp1)+1+exp(lp3))
  P4 <- 1/(exp(lp2)+ exp(lp3)+exp(lp1)+1)
  mChoices <- t(apply(cbind(P1,P2,P3,P4), 1, rmultinom, n = 1, size = 1))
  x5 <- apply(mChoices, 1, function(x) which(x==1))
  lp <-   0.05*x1 + 0.2*x2 + 0.1*x3 + 0.02*x4 + log(1.5)*(x5==1) + log(5)*(x5==2) + log(2)*(x5==3)
  Tm <- qweibull(runif(N,pweibull(xt,shape = 7.5, scale = 82*exp(lp)),1), shape=7.5, scale=82*exp(lp))
  Cens <- 100
  time_M <- pmin(Tm,Cens)
  event_M <- time_M == Tm })   
res.full_M <- weibreg(Surv(H$xt,H$time_M, H$event_M) ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + factor(x5), data = H)
```

So can anyone help me to modify this code so that I can get the starting age (xt) less than the corresponding failure time (time_M) and the fitted regression model have coefficients values close to that in the following equation
 (`lp <-   0.05*x1 + 0.2*x2 + 0.1*x3 + 0.02*x4 + log(1.5)*(x5==1) + log(5)*(x5==2) + log(2)*(x5==3)`)

Comment: Do you mean "left censored" or "right censored"?  What's your event?  Diagnosis or "onset of condition"?  Put another way, what's your time to event: "time from age 30 to diagnosis" or "time from onset of condition to diagnosis"?

Comment: Hi, my event here is the first diagnosis of a disease. and the time to event is "time from age 30 to diagnosis".

Comment: Ah-ha!  That's what I thought.  That's *right* censoring, not left...  But that's good, because it makes the answer easy...

Comment: Hi, I am sorry can I explain it again, my event here is the first diagnosis of a disease. I think the proper term is left truncated since my population cohort consists of individuals age 30 and older who have not diagnosed with my event of interest (disease) until the start of the study. And here my time scale is **age** not the time from the start of the study. Let me know if you need any further clarification

Comment: If the error is `Surv(xt, time_M, event_M) : Stop time must be > start time, NA created`, then you either need to throw out those rows where that condition fails or you need to add the simulated survival time to the simulated starting time.

Answer (score 0):

Your first comment implies that you want (possibly censored) times from age 30 to diagnosis.  You have two options: work with "survival times" or with the date of of the patients 30th birthday and their date of diagnosis.  It's easier to use the former, as it's easier to specify your censoring rate.

1. Generate an uncensored survival time (T) from the distribution of your choice.
2. Draw a random number from a Uniform(0, 1) distribution.  If this number is *less than* your censoring rate, the observation is censored: go to 3.  Otherwise, your uncensored observed survival time is (T).
3. Draw another random variable (X) from a Uniform(0, 1) distribution.  Set T = T*X.  This is your censored survival time.

This procedure will give you data from any distribution of survival times, censored at the rate of your choice.

However, my reading of your specification tells me that *every* participant will at some point be diagnosed with the condition of interest.  There are no competing risks.  Is this reasonable?

Your second comment is confusing.  Is your time to event (a) "time from age 30 to diagnosis" (which would imply right censoring) or (b) "time from onset of disease until diagnosis" (which would imply left censoring and could also involve right censoring).  If (a), my solution still holds.  If (b), you need to supply more information:

- What's the process (distribution) of time from age 30 to onset of disease?
- When/How frequently are diagnostic procedures conducted?
- What's the chance of a diagnostic procedure giving each of the following results: false positive, false negative, true positive, true negative

It's still possible to generate the data you want, but it's not as easy as in (a).

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarification I am quite new to survival modeling. I'll try to explain it clearly here. Let us assume that on Jan 1, 2000, I started my study on a cohort that contains individuals age 30 and above (10^5)(```xt=runif(N, 30, 80)```) and I have recorded the age of onset of a disease(Tm). Finally, I've censored the failure time beyond the age of 100.```Tm <- qweibull(runif(N,pweibull(xt,shape = 7.5, scale = 82*exp(lp)),1), shape=7.5, scale=82*exp(lp))
  Cens <- 100
  time_M <- pmin(Tm,Cens)
  event_M <- time_M == Tm```.